# Idle Time out Error

Tags: android, android-activity, mvvmcross, lifecycle

My MvvmCross Android Application running fine, it resume fine when resume done within reasonable time but it not resume well if the timespan too much . Instead of displaying the activity content it just display an actionbar with title without any content of menuitems. It yield an “Object reference null” type of exception.

I know this is Activity life cycle problem but not getting luck.

This is my code :

```
public class MyFragmentActivity : AppCompatActivity, IMvxEventSourceActivity
{

   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)

{

  base.OnCreate(bundle);
  CreateCalled.Raise(this, bundle);
  Mvx.Resolve();

}

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {

        DestroyCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        NewIntentCalled.Raise(this, intent);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        ResumeCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        PauseCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnPause();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        StartCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart();
        RestartCalled.Raise(this);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StopCalled.Raise(this);
        base.OnStop();
    }

    public override void StartActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
    {
        StartActivityForResultCalled.Raise(this, new MvxStartActivityForResultParameters(intent, requestCode));
        base.StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        ActivityResultCalled.Raise(this, new MvxActivityResultParameters(requestCode, resultCode, data));
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        SaveInstanceStateCalled.Raise(this, outState);
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            DisposeCalled.Raise(this);
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public event EventHandler DisposeCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> CreateWillBeCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> CreateCalled;
    public event EventHandler DestroyCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Intent>> NewIntentCalled;
    public event EventHandler ResumeCalled;
    public event EventHandler PauseCalled;
    public event EventHandler StartCalled;
    public event EventHandler RestartCalled;
    public event EventHandler StopCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<Bundle>> SaveInstanceStateCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<MvxStartActivityForResultParameters>> StartActivityForResultCalled;
    public event EventHandler<MvxValueEventArgs<MvxActivityResultParameters>> ActivityResultCalled;

}
```

Please help to resolve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why copy all that code? MvvmCross has build in support for AppCompat: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

You can inherit from MvxAppCompatActivity

```
public class LoginActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity<LoginViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView ( Resource.Layout.activity_login );
    }
}
```

If you want caching for Fragments you even can use MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity

Comment: @martijin00, I have 2 questions 1. Does MvxAppCompatActivity resolve my activity life cycle issues ?      2. Currently I am using MvvmCross 3.5.1,  and not able to getting MvxAppCompatActivity class, so should I upgrade mvvmCrooss to 4.0.

Comment: Yes it should solve your life cycle issue's, and you should update to 4.0 to be able to use it.

Comment: @martijin00, I updated mvvmcross 4.0 and now I getting lots of errors like "The type 'IMvxViewModel' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819'." for IMvxViewModel, IMvxView, IMvxDisposeSource, IMvxDataConsumer.

Comment: That sounds like a misconfiguration of your packages. You should be able to solve that by making sure that all packages are on the latest beta. If you need more detailed help i would recommend joining Slack: https://xamarinchat.herokuapp.com/